# How to get spheres in selected area in ThreeJS?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on an application where I use ThreeJS. Here I am obtaining a 3D model with spheres, as seen in the figure. My goal is to turn the spheres within this area red by using a select area. However, when doing this, spheres elsewhere, not the areas within the area, are turned red.

[image: 3D model with select area]

This is how to create spheres:

```
    lines.forEach(line => {
        const values = line.split('\t'); // tab separated
        if (values.length === 8) {
            const x = parseFloat(values[0]);
            const y = parseFloat(values[1]);
            const z = parseFloat(values[2]);
            const designvar = values[4];
            const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, defaultMaterial.clone());   
            scene.add(sphere); 
            sphere.designvar = designvar;  // id
       
            spheres.push(sphere);     

        }
        
    });
```

And this is how to create select area and colored spheres:

```
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
    var selectedMeshes = [];
    var selectionBox = document.getElementById("sel_box");
    let isOrbitControlEnabled = true;
    document.getElementById('forceareaadd').addEventListener('click', onPickAreaClick, false);
    var mouseDownCoords = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    var mouseUpCoords = { x: 0, y: 0 };
        
    function onPickAreaClick() {
        isOrbitControlEnabled = !isOrbitControlEnabled;
        controls.enabled = isOrbitControlEnabled;
        if (!isOrbitControlEnabled) {
        
        }
    }

    function getCursorPosition(e)
    {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e)
        {
        if (e.pageX || e.pageX == 0) return [e.pageX,e.pageY];
        var dE = document.documentElement || {};
        var dB = document.body || {};
        if ((e.clientX || e.clientX == 0) && ((dB.scrollLeft || dB.scrollLeft == 0) || (dE.clientLeft || dE.clientLeft == 0))) return [e.clientX + (dE.scrollLeft || dB.scrollLeft || 0) - (dE.clientLeft || 0),e.clientY + (dE.scrollTop || dB.scrollTop || 0) - (dE.clientTop || 0)];
        }
    return null;
    }

function mousedown(e)
    {
        if (!isOrbitControlEnabled) {
    var mxy = getCursorPosition(e);
    var box = document.getElementById("sel_box");
    mouseDownCoords.x = mxy[0];
    mouseDownCoords.y = mxy[1];
    box.orig_x = mxy[0];
    box.orig_y = mxy[1];
    box.style.left = mxy[0]+"px";
    box.style.top = mxy[1]+"px";
    box.style.display = "block";
    document.onmousemove = mousemove;
    document.onmouseup = mouseup;
    console.log("down x y: "+ mouseDownCoords.x + " " + mouseDownCoords.y);
    }
}

function mousemove(e)
    {
        if (!isOrbitControlEnabled) {
    var mxy = getCursorPosition(e);
    var box = document.getElementById("sel_box");
    if(mxy[0]-box.orig_x<0){
  box.style.left = mxy[0]+"px";
    
    }
    if(mxy[1]-box.orig_y<0){
      box.style.top = mxy[1]+"px";
    }
    box.style.width = Math.abs(mxy[0]-box.orig_x)+"px";
    box.style.height = Math.abs(mxy[1]-box.orig_y)+"px";
    }
}

function mouseup(e) {
    if (!isOrbitControlEnabled) {
        var box = document.getElementById("sel_box");
        var mxy = getCursorPosition(e);
        box.style.display = "none";
        box.style.width = "0";
        box.style.height = "0";
        document.onmousemove = function () {};
        document.onmouseup = function () {};

        mouseUpCoords.x = mxy[0];
        mouseUpCoords.y = mxy[1];
        console.log("up x y: " + mouseUpCoords.x + " " + mouseUpCoords.y);

        // Get the relative position of the design-part container
        var selBoxRect = box.getBoundingClientRect();
        var designContainerRect = document.getElementById("scene-container1").getBoundingClientRect();

        var designPartX = designContainerRect.left - selBoxRect.left;
        var designPartY = designContainerRect.top - selBoxRect.top;

        // Iterate through spheres and check if they are within the selection box
        spheres.forEach((sphere) => {
            const spherePosition = sphere.position.clone();
            const screenPosition = spherePosition.clone().project(camera);

            // Convert screen position to DOM coordinates
            const domX = (screenPosition.x + 1) / 2 * window.innerWidth + designPartX;
            const domY = (-screenPosition.y + 1) / 2 * window.innerHeight + designPartY;

            // Check if the sphere is within the selection box
            if (
                domX >= Math.min(mouseDownCoords.x, mouseUpCoords.x) &&
                domX <= Math.max(mouseDownCoords.x, mouseUpCoords.x) &&
                domY >= Math.min(mouseDownCoords.y, mouseUpCoords.y) &&
                domY <= Math.max(mouseDownCoords.y, mouseUpCoords.y)
            ) {
                console.log("sphere x y: " + domX + " " + domY);
                sphere.material.color.set(0xff0000); // Set to red color
                selectedMeshes.push(sphere);
            }
        });
    }
}



document.onmousedown = mousedown;
```

Also HTML here (simplified version):

```
<body>
    <div class="main-part" id="main-part">
      <div class="design-part" id="scene-container1">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="sel_box"></div>
</body>
```

How can I turn only the spheres within the select area red?